# how to solve typed error for mapStateToProps function

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux

Getting a type error that reads:

Argument of type '(state: AuthState) => AuthProps' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MapStateToPropsParam'.

Type '(state: AuthState) => AuthProps' is not assignable to type 'MapStateToProps'.

Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.

Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'AuthState'. Property 'auth' is missing in type '{}'.

I even specified the types below and it is still kicking up an error on mapStateToProps.

```
interface AuthProps {
  token?: string
}

interface ActionProps {
  otpLogin: () => void
}

interface AuthState {
  auth: { token: string }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AuthState): AuthProps => {
  return {token: state.auth.token};
};

const mapActionCreators = {
  otpLogin
};

export default connect<AuthProps, ActionProps, {}>(mapStateToProps, mapActionCreators)(AuthScreen);
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem based on the information you've provided.  Please add the declaration of `AuthScreen` and any referenced prop types to the question.